# A very simple HTML clarification needed

Tags: html

I have the following piece of code

```
           <li>
                 <label> Label: </label>
                  <p>I am label 1 </p>
               </li>
```

This prints out like

```
 1.  Label:

    I am label 1
```

how do I modify this so as it prints

```
Label: I am label 1
```

Comment: Do you need that text to be in a paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p>` is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) so you need to allow it to flow by using `display:inline` or `inline-block` (or `float` if you *must*):

```
li p {display:inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AsY29/

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
    <label> Label: </label>
    <span>I am label 1 </span>
</li>
```

Use span instead of p if you want it to display in the same line. p is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
       <li class="myli">
             <label class="mylabel"> Label: </label>
              <p class="inline-p">I am label 1 </p>
       </li>
```

CSS

```
.mylabel {display:inline-block;}
.inline-p {display:inline-block;}
li.myli {list-style-type:none;}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
li label, li p {
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you begin with a `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag than can you do like this:

```
ul li p {
  display: inline;
}
```

or

```
ol li p {
  display: inline;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eTILOgO/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Labels make sense only when correlated with `<input>` elements.  When a user clicks on a `<label>` element, the `<input>` it points to gets the focus and is selected. Checkboxes are toggled, etc.

```
<li>
    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input id="quantity" type="number"
           min="0" placeholder="Quantity (0 to delete)">
<li>
```

The label points to the input. With CSS, you can give `form label` a width of `100px` and float it to the left. You can tell `form li` to clear left.  `form ol` should have `list-style-type: none`. There's no need for `<p>` here. Work with the system; don't fight it.

If you just have plain text, use plain text, not labels.  On the other hand, you may want to style a definition list as in the old `<dl compact>`.  I'm not sure how you get the `<dt>` and `<dd>` on the same line.